# nbstripout: what does `diff=ipynb` do in .gitattributes?

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

I'm using nbstripout to remove Jupyter output before committing. nbstripout generated a `.gitattribute` file that looks like this:

```
*.ipynb filter=nbstripout

*.ipynb diff=ipynb
```

This works as expected, whenever I `git status`, `git diff`, or `git commit`, it doesn't include Jupyter outputs. However, when I remove the second line, it does the same thing.

What does `*.ipynb diff=ipynb` do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`diff` attribute](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_generating_diff_text), when set to a string, references a diff driver.

But the first attributes reference a content filter driver using the *same* command.
Since the content filter driver is involved when doing a git diff ([through the smudge command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366267/6309)), it does the same operation (meaning it changes the content of the working tree file compared with the index)

Comment: So it's supposed to be the same without the second line?

Comment: @LeoJiang Yes, the smudge content filter would play the same role as the diff attributes.